# Modify a variable in between thread groups

Tags: jmeter

Trying to control thread groups by a variable which I would like to modify in between the thread groups ( I execute the TGs in sequence). Example:

```
Test Plan
JSR223Preprocessor or Listener       #tried them both
--> vars.put(key,Integer.toString(1));
ThreadGroup
---> x=key
JSR223Preprocessor/Listener 
--> vars.put(key,Integer.toString(2));
ThreadGroup
---> x=key
```

Both ThreadGroups will use the last value of key (2 in the example above)? How can I modify the variable in between the Thread Groups executions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) chapter of JMeter Documentation:

   > Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

   it means that whatever value you set using `vars.put()` function will remain [local to the current thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (virtual user), if you need to pass the value between thread groups - you will need to switch to `props` shorthand instead or go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)
2. According to [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) chapter of JMeter Documentation

   > **Please note that Timers, Assertions, Pre- and Post-Processors are only processed if there is a sampler to which they apply.** Logic Controllers and Samplers are processed in the order in which they appear in the tree. Other test elements are processed according to the scope in which they are found, and the type of test element. [Within a type, elements are processed in the order in which they appear in the tree].

   also according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) in case of PreProcessor the code is being executed before each sampler and in case of listener after each sampler, not sure if this is something you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the JSR below relevant Thread Group if you don't want to affect all Thread Groups

See [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

> Some elements in the test trees are strictly hierarchical (Listeners, Config Elements, Post-Processors, Pre-Processors, Assertions, Timers)